# react native delete item form array by key

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am trying to delete an item from my array by specific key.

this is my code:

Code that generating multi TextInput:

```
var OtherValuesArr = [];
const OtherValues = () =>{
    for(let i=0; i<otherValuesNumber; i++){
        var theOutPut = (
          <View style={styles.otherValContainerLoop}>
            <View style={styles.otherValContainerLoopCancel}>
              <TouchablePlatform containerStyle={styles.otherValContainerLoopCancelTouch} onPress={()=>{otherValueRemove(i)}}>
                <Icon name="minus" style={styles.otherValContainerLoopCancelTouchIcon} />
              </TouchablePlatform>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.otherValContainerLoopInput}>
              <TextInput
                  style={[styles.profileFormInputSection_INPUT,!variantValueHandler && {backgroundColor:'#fab8c0'}]}
                  onChangeText={(text) => {setOthersValue(text,i);}}
                  value={othervaluearr[i]}
                  placeholder={t(trans.optionvalue)}
                  placeholderTextColor={placeHolderTextColor}
                  keyboardType="default"
              />
            </View>
        </View>
        );
        OtherValuesArr[i]=theOutPut;
    }
    return OtherValuesArr;
}
```

Code that handling the inputs (update,remove):

```
const [othervaluearr,setOtherValueArr] = useState([]);
const setOthersValue = (text,i) =>{
  setOtherValueArr(oldArray => ({...oldArray,[i]:text}));
}
const otherValueRemove = (index) =>{
  console.log(othervaluearr);
}
```

this is the output of console.log(othervaluearr); :

```
{"0": "Asdasd", "1": "Asdasdxx"}
```

i want to remove a specific key, for example:
when index = 0, i want to remove "0" and get new array with the following values:

```
{"1": "Asdasdxx"}
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

try this :
var index1 = othervaluearr.indexOf("Asdasd");

othervaluearr.splice(index1, 1);

Comment: thanks but i want to delete by the key, not value.

Comment: i also got: othervaluearr.indexOf is not a function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you save an object inside of your array. Your array has **one** element and it's the object with the values you have.

To solve this you must change the way you save the new data

1st solution

```
const setOthersValue = (text,i) =>{
  setOtherValueArr(oldArray => [...oldArray,{key: i, value: text}];
}
```

if you want a stable key. If you want to delete an object, you will search the object with key x and you will delete it.

if you don't want a stable key. just do this simple solution.

2nd solution

```
const setOthersValue = (text) =>{
  setOtherValueArr(oldArray => [...oldArray, text];
}

const otherValueRemove = (index) =>{
  othervaluearr.splice(index,1);
}
```

Remember array is with `[ ]` and object with `{ }`

Comment: thanks, i understand you, but i have a problem with the 1st solution: i got: [{"key": 0, "value": "A"}, {"key": 0, "value": "As"}, {"key": 0, "value": "Asd"}, {"key": 0, "value": "Asda"}, {"key": 0, "value": "Asdas"}, {"key": 0, "value": "Asdasd"}, {"key": 1, "value": "B"}, {"key": 1, "value": "Bb"}, {"key": 1, "value": "Bbb"}, {"key": 1, "value": "Bbbb"}, {"key": 1, "value": "Bbbbb"}], i am expecting to update key:0 and not to add multi keys with same value

Comment: Then you want something like that:

[
{
key: 0,
value: ["aa", "aasdasd", "asdasdas"]
},
{
key: 1,
value: ["bb", "bbbbbasd", "bbasdbb"]
}
]

Comment: i will update my question may this will help more...i am working with multi TextInput, wait a minute

Comment: i want when i am in input with index 0 and i am writing for example: abab, so key:0 text:abab....when i update the text to zfzf, i want to remove the old key:0 and update the new: key:0 text:zfzf

Comment: copyarray = [...oldArray]
//you looking for key = keyX and the new value is newValueY

for(let i = 0; i < copyarray.length(); i++){
if(copyarray[i].key === keyX){
   copyarray[i].value = newValuey
}
}

setOtherValueArr(...copyarray)